# MongoDB check for null fields in $switch statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Im trying to check for null/missing fields in my $switch statement but it's not working. Here is my code

```
$switch: {
                branches: [
                    {
                        case: {
                            $and: [
                                { $gte: ["$SmartPriority", 6] },
                                { $ne: ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", null] },
                                { $ne: ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", ""] },
                                { $ne: ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", false] }
                            ]
                        },
                        then: "Greater than"
                    }
                ],
                default: "EMPTY"
            }
```

Even if it has $ne to "null" or "false" it doesn't show EMPTY (default value). What should my expression be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this

```
"$switch": {
   "branches": [
    { "case": { "$gte": ["$SmartPriority", 6] }, "then": "Greater than" },
    { "case": { "$ne": ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", null] }, "then": "EMPTY" },
    { "case": { "$ne": ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", ""] }, "then": "Greater than" },
    { "case": { "$ne": ["$FlashTRFPromotionDate", false] }, "then": "EMPTY" }
  ],
  "default": "EMPTY"
}
```